# jQuery array multiplication

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two different arrays. I want sum of arrays by multiplying with each element with another array. For example:

```
function get_total() {
    var i = 0;
    var arr = [];
    var gift_val_len = $('.gift_value').length;
    $('.gift_value').each(function() {
        arr[i++]= parseFloat($(this).val());  // Or this.innerHTML, this.innerText
    });
    var j = 0;
    var arr1 = [];
    $('.gift_number').each(function() {
        arr1[j++]= parseFloat($(this).val());  // Or this.innerHTML, this.innerText
    });
}
```

Now there are two different arrays like arr1=[15, 20, 25], arr2=[1, 3, 5] and I want result like ((15*1) + (20*3) + (25*5)). How can we achieve this?

Comment: Do arrays have the same length always ?

Comment: yes.. both array will have same length always..

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a single line with pure JavaScript (no jQuery), using the built-in `.map()` method:

```js
var arr1=[15, 20, 25], arr2=[1, 3, 5];
var sum = 0;
var arr3 = arr1.map(function(x, index) {
  var curMult = x * arr2[index];
  sum += curMult;
  return curMult;
});
console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
console.log(arr3);
console.log(sum);
```

This will also sum the elements, as mentioned in the question.

**Note**: the arrays must be of the same length, otherwise the code will crash.

Comment: The question says sum, so maybe add `.reduce(function(a, b) { return a+b;}, 0);` ?

Comment: What I was just going to write. You can make it a bit more defensive by:  arr1.map(function(x, i) { return x * arr2[i] || x * 1; }); 

If there is any chance the array might not have the same number of elements.

Comment: @Chintan thanks,but since it's already iterating the array, no need for another loop. Edited the answer to add sum.

Comment: @Deshiknaves valid concern, but IMO it's OK to demand arrays of same length. Many built-in methods also throw errors or crash with invalid input.

Answer (score 1):

### Try This:

- Inside `get_total` function, dispatch the `function mulitply` below with `arr1,arr2` params.
- Or assign it to a variable, like `var mult = multiply(arr1,arr2);`

```js
function multiply(arr1, arr2) {
  var res = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    res.push(arr1[i] * arr2[i]);
  };
  return res
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To reduce an array to a single value you can use  [Array Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
// Code goes here

var arr1=[15, 20, 25], arr2=[1, 3, 5];


var result = arr1.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex) {
  var computedValue = currentValue * arr2[currentIndex];
  return previousValue + computedValue;
});
document.write(result);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Array.protototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) might be a good way to handle this.

```
function multiplyArrays (array1, array2) {
    return array1.reduce(function(prev, curr, i) {
      return prev + (curr * array2[i]);
    }, 0);
}
```